# Angular Multiple Drag and Drop (ng2-dragula)

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, draggable

I'm looking for drag and drop library which supports multiple drag. But I couldn't find any for angular 2+. ng2-dragula supports what we want, except multiple drag and drop. Can any one suggest any library or how to overwrite ng2 dragula to achieve same. 
  Here are the features what we are looking:

1. Drag to particular position in target container
2. Drag multiple items
3. Drag inside same container
4. Work for any kind of element
5. Support both copy and move to target

Comment: You can try [`angular-sortablejs`](https://github.com/SortableJS/angular-sortablejs#angular-sortablejs) for your features.

Comment: Thank you very much. Even in sortable js there is no option for multiple drag

Comment: What do you mean by multiple drag?

Comment: Select multiple items and then drag

Comment: did you got answer for this?

Comment: I used ngx-dnd and implemented multiple drag and drop on top of that

Comment: can you add that in answer how you implemented the same for multi darg drop?

Comment: Generally you can use ng2-dragula for this - look hire: https://jsfiddle.net/tx7aym91/4/

Answer (score 5):

Based on [this comment](https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula/issues/50#issuecomment-384799256) on [github `bevacqua/dragula` issue: Drag and drop multiple items #50](https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula/issues/50).

I've made some improvement which allows multiple item drag and drops by selected item: https://jsfiddle.net/twfcd5hx/1/

And on ng2-dragula: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-dragula-base-i41w6c?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Related code (note that [I've tried using the pure angular way](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-dragula-base-ajadjg?file=src/app/app.component.ts) but not working as intended, will update once I found the pure angular one):

```
this.dragulaService.cloned("dnd").subscribe(({ clone, original, cloneType }) => {
      this.mirrorContainer = $('.gu-mirror').first();
      this.mirrorContainer.removeClass('ex-over');
      this.selectedItems = $('.ex-over');
      this.hasMultiple = this.selectedItems.length > 1 || (this.selectedItems.length == 1 && !$(original).hasClass('ex-over'));
      if (this.hasMultiple) {
        $('.gu-transit').addClass('ex-over');
        this.selectedItems = $('.ex-over');
        this.mirrorContainer.empty();
        var height = 0,
          width = 0;
        let temp = this.mirrorContainer;
        this.selectedItems.each(function (index) {
          var item = $(this);
          var mirror = item.clone(true);
          mirror.removeClass('ex-over gu-transit');
          temp.append(mirror);
          temp.css('background-color', 'transparent');
          item.addClass('gu-transit');
          var rect = item[0].getBoundingClientRect();
          height += rect.height;
          width = rect.width;
        });
        this.mirrorContainer = temp;
        this.mirrorContainer.css('height', height + 'px');
      }
    });
```

---

You would need to declare `import $ from 'jquery';` on `.ts` file and install `@types/jquery`, `jquery`

Explanation:

`this.mirrorContainer = $('.gu-mirror').first();` grab the mirror container `dragula` creates by default

`this.mirrorContainer.removeClass('ex-over');` multi-selected items will have this class, but we don't want it on the ones in the mirror

`this.selectedItems = $('.ex-over');` get the multi-selected items

`this.hasMultiple = this.selectedItems.length > 1 || (this.selectedItems.length == 1 && !$(original).hasClass('ex-over'));` check if multiple items are selected, and takes into account where they start dragging from an item that hasn't been selected

```
if (this.hasMultiple) { // we have multiple items selected
    $('.gu-transit').addClass('ex-over'); // edge case: if they started dragging from an unselected item, adds the selected item class
    this.selectedItems = $('.ex-over'); // update list of selected items in case of edge case above
    this.mirrorContainer.empty();  // clear the mirror container, we're going to fill it with clones of our items
    var height = 0,
      width = 0; // will track final dimensions of the mirror container
    let temp = this.mirrorContainer; // used to temporary store this.mirrorContainer since otherwise would return undefined
    this.selectedItems.each(function (index) { // clone the selected items into the mirror container
      var item = $(this); // the item
      var mirror = item.clone(true); // clone the item
      mirror.removeClass('ex-over gu-transit'); // remove the state classes if necessary
      temp.append(mirror); //add the clone to mirror container
      temp.css('background-color', 'transparent');
      item.addClass('gu-transit'); //add drag state class to item
      var rect = item[0].getBoundingClientRect(); // update the dimensions for the mirror container
      height += rect.height;
      width = rect.width;
    });
    this.mirrorContainer = temp; // restore this.mirrorContainer value after updated
    this.mirrorContainer.css('height', height + 'px'); //set final height of mirror container
  }
```

Note that in the following code I was using `el.remove()` to remove the dragged element being stored to target element because I've made the `moveback()` and `moveto()` function ([related explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54626215/moving-element-from-one-array-into-another)).

```
this.dragulaService.drop("dnd")
  .subscribe(({ name, el, target, source, sibling }) => {
    if (source.attributes[2].value === "data" && (target.attributes[3].value === "ct" || target.attributes[2].value === "target")) {
      if (this.target.length > 0) {
        this.placeholdertarget = false;
      }
      if (this.data.length < 1) {
        this.placeholderdata = true;
      }
      if (!this.hasMultiple) {
        let target = document.getElementsByClassName('target');
        for (let i = target.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
          if (target[i].className.includes('ex-over') && i >= 0) {
            this.removeClass(target[i], 'ex-over');
          }
        }
      } else {
        el.remove();
        this.moveto();
      }
      for (let i = 0; i < this.target.length; i++) {
        this.target[i].state = false;
      }
      this.challtarget = false;
    } else if (source.attributes[2].value === "target" && (target.attributes[3].value === "cd" || target.attributes[2].value === "data")) {
      if (this.target.length < 1) {
        this.placeholdertarget = true;
      }
      if (this.data.length > 0) {
        this.placeholderdata = false;
      }
      if (!this.hasMultiple) {
        let target = document.getElementsByClassName('data');
        for (let i = target.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
          if (target[i].className.includes('ex-over') && i >= 0) {
            this.removeClass(target[i], 'ex-over');
          }
        }
      } else {
        el.remove();
        this.moveback();
      }
      for (let i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
        this.data[i].state = false;
      }
      this.challdata = false;
    } else {
      // console.log('spilled');
      // this.dragulaService.find('dnd').drake.cancel(true);
    }
  });
```