# Moving element from one array into another

Tags: javascript, angular

I've tried to make the following **[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-dragula-base-uabwzg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)** which use `ng2-dragula`. My problem laid in the `moveback()` and `moveto()` function which are supposed to move from one array into another when the element was selected. I was able to detect which element was selected but unable to move them completely (some element was left over).

Related Code:

```
  moveback() {
    let target = document.getElementsByClassName('target');
    for (let i = 0; i < target.length; i++) {
      if (target[i].className.includes('ex-over')) {
        this.removeClass(target[i], 'ex-over');
        this.data.push({ name: target[i].innerHTML });
        this.target.splice(i, 1);
      }
    }
  }

  moveto() {
    let target = document.getElementsByClassName('data');
    for (let i = 0; i < target.length; i++) {
      if (target[i].className.includes('ex-over')) {
        this.removeClass(target[i], 'ex-over');
        this.target.push({ name: target[i].innerHTML });
        this.data.splice(i, 1);
      }
    }
  }
```

I've found two [related(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45920086/3654837), [related(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31887967/javascript-move-objects-from-one-array-to-another-best-approach) question which asks similar thing but it's not working in my case. My approach was detecting either the element contains a certain class name then remove the class and move them to another array and remove it from the original array. But it's not working like intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your `for` condition as below.

```
for (let i = target.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {...}
```

The issue with your logic is, If you select `2nd & 3rd` element and apply `moveto` then for `2nd` element it will work fine. But then in your actual `this.target` array will be changed. Now `3rd` element will become `2nd` because of your line `this.target.splice(i, 1);`. So when you move `3rd` element in `for` loop iteration, it will actually move `4th` one.

[Check with Updated fiddle Here](https://ng2-dragula-base-mumrjc.stackblitz.io)